# firebase realtime database find node by child value

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, find

I have the following structure:

```
root
  -LKMsdf2_Qxbwtv4238D
     details
       uid: john

  -YKMWrmj_QxbwtvSBM5A
     details
       uid: tony

  -R45Wrmj_Qxbf321BMd4
     details
       uid: karina
```

How can I find the ref key under 'root' by its uid:

e.g: by uid:karina I need to get the ref key -R45Wrmj_Qxbf321BMd4

is there a way to use some wildcard like /root/{recordid}/details/uid or something?

**======== Thanks for the hints! ====  here is my final solution ================**

```
findEntry = function(targetUid) {
var entriesRef = db.ref('root');
return entriesRef.once('value')
    .then((snapshot)=>{
        var id = []; // found id

        snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot)=>{
            var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
            var childData = childSnapshot.val();
            var found = (childData.uid === targetUid);
            if (found) {
                console.log('Found for uid:' + targetUid  + ': ' + childKey);
                id = childKey;
            }
            return found; // true - breaks the forEach, false - continue
        });
    if (!id) {
        console.log('Not Found for uid:' + targetUid);
    }
    return id;
  });
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the best you can do is child (key) search and equality (see the example here https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#equalTo)

```
// Find all dinosaurs whose height is exactly 25 meters.
var ref = firebase.database().ref("dinosaurs");
ref.orderByChild("height").equalTo(25).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.key);
});
```

There isn't a way to query deeper than that.

You could have other structures for reverse lookups, flatten out your data or solve it in a different way.

Comment: I've marked z5h reply because it helped me.
I've added my final solution to the post.
I'm not sure if it's the best way because it's my first try with js and firebase. 
What do you think ?

Comment: Of course this works, but you are moving data to the client side to search. If you aren't searching through much data this will be fine. As the data set grows this will get slower and cost more money as you will be moving more data around.